# Fatal error in starting up OpenCV 2.4.6 on VS 2008, file not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv, application-settings

I am using this tutorial to get started with OpenCV 2.4.6 on VS 2008:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

I followed all instructions (my OpenCV is not in the default Program Files (x86) folder, it's in

```
C:\opencv_built
```

Unlike in the tutorial, I put very simple code, just to make sure all included files are reachable and if it builds successfully etc:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream> // for standard I/O
#include <string>   // for strings
#include <iomanip>  // for controlling float print precision
#include <sstream>  // string to number conversion

#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // Gaussian Blur
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  // OpenCV window I/O
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

double getPSNR ( const Mat& I1, const Mat& I2);
Scalar getMSSIM( const Mat& I1, const Mat& I2);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

But I get a fatal error when I try to build:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp': No such file or directory   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\firstopencv\firstopencv\firstopencv.cpp    17
```

This is obviously referring to this line:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // Gaussian Blur
```

I don't know where to find the dll files, or what to do next? I know this must be really easy but I've searched for any of the dll files, eg.

> opencv_core243d.lib

but I get no search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the fix was this:

Under Linker -> General -> **Additional Library Dependencies**

I put:

```
C:\opencv_built\lib\Debug
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Check your path to **\vc10** folder. It should be either:

```
C:\opencv_built\build\x86\vc10
```

or

```
C:\opencv_built\x86\vc10
```

---

**2.** Go to

```
Start>Edit environment variables for your account>Under System variables > New...
```

Variable Name: **OPENCV_DIR**

Variable Value: **Insert your path from step 1 here.**

---

**3.** Open Visual Studio, make new project, go to **Property Pages**

---

**4.** Under **C/C++ > Additional Include Directories**

Insert `$(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include`

---

**5.** Under **Linker > General > Additional Include Directories**

Insert `$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib`

---

**6a.** (For **DEBUG** property!) Under **Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies**

Insert

```
opencv_core246d.lib
opencv_imgproc246d.lib
opencv_highgui246d.lib
opencv_ml246d.lib
opencv_video246d.lib
opencv_features2d246d.lib
opencv_calib3d246d.lib
opencv_objdetect246d.lib
opencv_contrib246d.lib
opencv_legacy246d.lib
opencv_flann246d.lib
```

---

**6b.** (For **RELEASE** property!) Under **Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies**

Insert

```
opencv_core246.lib
opencv_imgproc246.lib
opencv_highgui246.lib
opencv_ml246.lib
opencv_video246.lib
opencv_features2d246.lib
opencv_calib3d246.lib
opencv_objdetect246.lib
opencv_contrib246.lib
opencv_legacy246.lib
opencv_flann246.lib
```

---

This should be enough. If you get missing .dll window after running code, copy desired .dll from your `C:\opencv_built\build\x86\vc10\bin` or `C:\opencv_built\x86\vc10\bin` to your project folder.

Comment: Okay I did what you said and I am no longer getting that error! However, now I get this error: FATAL ERROR LNK1104: cannot open file opencv_core246d.lib (although I entered it in the additional dependencies). I then pasted opencv_core246d.dll into the path of my project which is : C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\firstopencv\, and I also pasted it in the x64 subdirectory, but this opencv_core246d.dll is still not found!

Comment: Wait. What is your target machine on which you would like to develop applications? x64 or x86 ?

Comment: It's x64. But I didn't use the pathnames that included x86, like C:\opencv_built\x86\vc10\bin. Instead I used the real path I found on this machine, which was: C:\opencv_built\bin.

Comment: What do you have in your C:\opencv_built\ folder?

Comment: I have the following folders: apps/, bin/, CMakefiles/, data/, doc/, include/, include1/, install/, junk/, lib/, modules/, opencv2/, unix-install/, win-install/, and some CMake and VS files.

Comment: From where did you download OpenCV library? Did you download and extract? Or anything else?

Comment: I didn't do it. I've been given a workstation on which to do some image processing, some other staff set it up for me and now they're not exactly reachable :S and I don't have admin access.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a dll file, it's a header file. The file is called imgproc.hpp

If you compiler can't find it it's either because it isn't there, or it's because you haven't told your compiler where to find it.

The important part for VS is the “Additional Include Directories”, look at that part again on the web page you followed.

Comment: Right! I got mixed up. I searched for imgproc.hpp and I found it in this directory: *C:\Working Opecv copy\opencv_built\include\opencv2\imgproc*. So then under Linker -> General, I changed the value of Additional Library dependencies to *C:\Working Opecv copy\opencv_built\include*. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Additional **Include** Directories